# PSS/E fortran array modules

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I am developing a user-written control model for an inverter in PSS/E through Fortran language. I want to link this control model to a standard generator model.

I've already check that the control model works fine. I am entering 2 input commands: Real Power (P) and Reactive Power (Q). I have check through internal variables that the model takes well these values defined by me. And the outputs of this control model are "correct" both outpus signals are what are supposed to be.

The problem is that I'm not be able to link it to the standard generator model. As this model is contained in an external .dll file I use the USE [MODULE] statement at the beginning of the code and in MODE 3 I just write:

```
WIPCMD1(MC)=VAR(L+5)
WIQCMD1(MC)=VAR(L+4)
```

Where MC is the machine index where apply both models, WIPCMD and WIQCMD are the arrays that work as input of the generator model and `VAR(L+5)` and `VAR(L+4)` are the outputs from my user-written control model.

I know that the connection is wrong because when I change the 2 inputs of the control model, the 2 outputs of this control change too, but the outputs of the generator model are always de same (I think that are the initialized ones from the power flow).

Another possible cause is that I am compiling wrong the files in the PSS/E Environment Manager: I just put the my control model .flx file inside "User Model Fortran Source Files" and the .obj file with the same name of the .mod file that contains the GEPVMODULE in "User Model Object, Library Files". I use the resultant .dll file.

Any idea? Bellow is the whole code of the .flx control model.

Thank you very much.

Regards

```
      SUBROUTINE INVCTRLELEC (MC,ISLOT)
C
      USE GEPVMODULE
C
$INSERT COMON4.INS
C
      INTEGER I,J,K,L,MC,ISLOT,BS
      INTEGER IERR1,IERR3
      REAL VINP1,VINP2,VINP3,VINP4,VINP5,VINP6,VINP7,VINP8,VINP9,VINP10
      REAL VOUT1,VOUT2,VOUT3,VOUT4,VOUT5,VOUT6,VOUT7,VOUT8,VOUT9,VOUT10
C
C
      I=STRTIN(4,ISLOT)
      J=STRTIN(1,ISLOT)
      K=STRTIN(2,ISLOT)
      L=STRTIN(3,ISLOT)
C
      CALL FLOW1(I,L+6,L+1,L+7)
C
      IF (MODE.EQ.8)
      .  CON_DSCRPT(1)='Kqi'
      .  CON_DSCRPT(2)='Kvi'
      .  CON_DSCRPT(3)='Ihql'
      .  CON_DSCRPT(4)='Ipmax'
      .  CON_DSCRPT(5)='Iphl'
      .  CON_DSCRPT(6)='Vmaxcl'
      .  CON_DSCRPT(7)='Vmincl'
      .  CON_DSCRPT(8)='Vdc'
      .  CON_DSCRPT(9)='Porder'
      .  CON_DSCRPT(10)='Qorder'
      .  ICON_DSCRPT(1)='Bus origen'
      .  ICON_DSCRPT(2)='Bus destino'
      .  ICON_DSCRPT(3)='Identificador'
      .  RETURN
      ...FIN
C
      IF (MODE.GT.4) GO TO 1000
C
      GO TO (100,200,300,400), MODE
C
  100 VOUT1=CON(J+9)-VAR(L+1)
      VINP1=INT_MODE1(1.0,VOUT1,K,IERR1)
C
      VOUT3=VOUT2-VAR(L+2)
      VINP3=INT_MODE1(1.0,VOUT3,K+1,IERR3)

      VAR(L+2)=ABS(VOLT(ICON(I)))
C     
      VAR(L+5)=WIPCMD1(MC)
      VAR(L+4)=WIQCMD1(MC)
C
      RETURN
C
  200 VAR(L+2)=ABS(VOLT(ICON(I)))
C
      VINP1=CON(J+9)-VAR(L+1)
      VOUT1=INT_MODE2(1.0,VINP1,K)
      VAR(L)=CON(J+9)
C
      VINP2=VOUT1*CON(J)
      VOUT2=MIN(CON(J+5),MAX(CON(J+6),VINP2))
C  
      VINP3=VOUT2-VAR(L+2)
      VOUT3=INT_MODE2(1.0,VINP3,K+1)
      VAR(L+11)=VOUT3*CON(J+1)
C
      VINP5=VAR(L+5)
      VOUT5=((CON(J+3))**(2)-(VAR(L+5))**(2))**(0.5)
C
      VINP6=VOUT5
      VOUT6=MIN(CON(J+2),VINP6)
      VAR(L+8)=VOUT6
C
      VINP7=VAR(L+2)
      VOUT7=-0.5+0.01733*(VINP7*360-360)-0.0117*(CON(J+7)-560)+VAR(L+6)*1/4.37
      VAR(L+9)=VOUT7
C
      VINP4=VOUT3*CON(J+1)
      VOUT4=MIN(VOUT6,MAX((MAX(VOUT7,-VOUT6)),VINP4))
      VAR(L+4)=VOUT4
C
      VINP8=VAR(L+2)
      VOUT8=MAX(0.01,VAR(L+2))
C
      VINP9=CON(J+8)
      VAR(L+3)=CON(J+8)
      VOUT9=VINP9/VOUT8
C
      VINP10=VOUT9
      VOUT10=MIN(MIN(CON(J+3),CON(J+4)),VINP10)
      VAR(L+5)=VOUT10
C
      RETURN
C
  300 VAR(L+2)=ABS(VOLT(ICON(I)))
C
      VINP1=CON(J+9)-VAR(L+1)
      VOUT1=INT_MODE3(1.0,VINP1,K)
      VAR(L)=CON(J+9)
C
      VINP2=VOUT1*CON(J)
      VOUT2=MIN(CON(J+5),MAX(CON(J+6),VINP2))
C  
      VINP3=VOUT2-VAR(L+2)
      VOUT3=INT_MODE3(1.0,VINP3,K+1)
      VAR(L+11)=VOUT3*CON(J+1)
C
      VINP5=VAR(L+5)
      VOUT5=((CON(J+3))**(2)-(VAR(L+5))**(2))**(0.5)
C
      VINP6=VOUT5
      VOUT6=MIN(CON(J+2),VINP6)
      VAR(L+8)=VOUT6
C
      VINP7=VAR(L+2)
      VOUT7=-0.5+0.01733*(VINP7*360-360)-0.0117*(CON(J+7)-560)+VAR(L+6)*1/4.37
      VAR(L+9)=VOUT7
C
      VINP4=VOUT3*CON(J+1)
      VOUT4=MIN(VOUT6,MAX((MAX(VOUT7,-VOUT6)),VINP4))
      VAR(L+4)=VOUT4
C
      VINP8=VAR(L+2)
      VOUT8=MAX(0.01,VAR(L+2))
C
      VINP9=CON(J+8)
      VAR(L+3)=CON(J+8)
      VOUT9=VINP9/VOUT8
C
      VINP10=VOUT9
      VOUT10=MIN(MIN(CON(J+3),CON(J+4)),VINP10)
      VAR(L+5)=VOUT10     
C     
      WIPCMD1(MC)=VAR(L+5)
      WIQCMD1(MC)=VAR(L+4)
C 
      VAR(L+12)=MC
      VAR(L+13)=ISLOT
C      
      RETURN
C
  400 NINTEG=MAX(NINTEG,K+3)
      RETURN
C
      IF (MODE.EQ.6) GO TO 2000
C
  900 RETURN
 1000 RETURN
 2000 RETURN
      RETURN
      END
```

Comment: How do you know you cannot link to the standard generator module?  If there is an error, it would be helpful if you showed what the error is by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21052724/edit) the post itself.

Comment: You must show your code, your commands and the errors you get, otherwise noone can know what is going on.

Comment: Hi. You both are right. I've just edited my fortran code of the control model. Besides, I've given more details in the question. Thanks

Comment: I don't get any error message, only that when I change the commands at the control model, the outputs change too but the outputs of the generator model are always the same. Even if, for example, I order a control model input P=0, I obtain a control model output VAR(L+5)=0 but the generator model keeps injecting the same active power anyway (P>>0)... So I think that the generator model doesn't recognize as it input the value of VAR(L+5)

Comment: @VladimirF You can maybe edit the question or suggest changes. That's the Stackoverflow spirit, isn't?

Comment: No, making a readable program from a bunch of Spaghetti isn't in the SO spirit. I don't even know the purpose of the code, how could I fix it?